# using takeUntilDestroyed in a class (not a component or directive)

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use takeUntilDestroyed in a class (not a component or directive)?

I tried the following however I am getting this exception:

```
preview-e79c0c20ea05a.js:2 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`.
```

```
export class MyTestClass {
  destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  constructor(
    public overlay: OverlayRef,
  ) {
    this.overlay
      .backdropClick()
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed())
      .subscribe(() => {
        // 
      });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in the error message it must be called from an injection context. If you inject your class using the angular DI it is not problem.

Comment: Based on your question and code, maybe what you need is just to make your class to become an ngular service I would say.

Comment: So since I need to create instances using new MyTestClass(...), and subscribe to the backdropclick event, is there another way of using takeUntilDestroyed? Or would I be better off using DI, and adding MyTestClass in the providers of the component that uses it?

Comment: Yes, you should use TestBed for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create your class outside of DI you can pass that destroyRef in the constructor :

```
export class MyTestClass {
  constructor(
    public overlay: OverlayRef,
    destroyRef: DestroyRef,
  ) {
    this.overlay
      .backdropClick()
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(destroyRef))
      .subscribe(() => {
        // 
      });
  }
}

describe('', () => {
  let destroyRef!: DestroyRef;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    });
    destroyRef = TestBed.inject(DestroyRef);
  });

  it('should ...', () => {
    new MyTestClass(..., destroyRef);
  });
});
```